# Interactive Voice Response in German

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, ivr

I'm trying to create an IVR: The user should call a phone number and speak to a AI with natural language.

I searched for a solution and found Google's Telephony gateway, Twilio's Autopilot and Amazon's Lex. They all seem to be very good, but they just support English.
I need an IVR for German.

Maybe I could connect some services like Google's TTS and STT, Dialogflow and a service for phone calls? But I'm not sure how to do this.

Does someone know a good solution to create german phone bot?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/08/introducing-50-additional-text-to-speech-voices-with-amazon-polly-integration.html

Comment: @alexBaban: Thanks for the link. So, a TTS would maybe work for german. That's great. Now, I only need a working STT.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While Autopilot only supports English right now, you can build and control a voice IVR using [TwiML with `<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) which does support German speech to text when you set [`input` to "speech"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input) and [`language` to "DE-de"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#language).

Using this you could build a simple command based IVR. To make a natural language capable AI, you could look into [IBM's Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-getting-started), [which supports German](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-language-support). Or [Azure Cognitive Services Luis](https://www.luis.ai/home) [which supports German too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-language-support).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With Google Telephony Gateway and Dialogflow you are out of luck. Dialogflow supports German, but the telephony is a beta and only supports English for now (it will transcribe your German speech as it was English). See the documentation [Here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/language?authuser=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Voxibot / Voximal solution.
They support most of the STT / TTS engine(a lot of languages), and you can connect your chatbot or voice service with the VoiceXML language...

[Web site](https://www.voxibot.com)